# K3 gravitational instanton

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, specific-reference

Could you please recommend a sufficiently elementary introduction to K3 gravitational instanton in general relativity and the problem of finding its explicit form?

Under 'sufficiently elementary' I mean the texts geared at physicists with basic knowledge of general realtivity but not much more than that (i.e. with almost no knowledge of modern differential geometry and algebraic geometry).  To give a hint, I find the description of the problem in the book *Solitons, Instantons and Twistors* by Maciej Dunajski way too terse.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I really don't know how elementary you want it, but you can try starting with the references cited by [this article by Page](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269378903052), perhaps the appendix of [this article of Gibbons and Pope](http://www.springerlink.com/content/u120661603638751/). You may also consider [this article of Biquard and Minerbe](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5133) and its references.

Comment: How are you supposed to have a basic knowledge of general relativity with no knowledge of differential geometry?  How would you even talk about the metric tensor?

Comment: @Jonathan: the emphasis in my question was on *modern* differential geometry, i.e. I do know tensor calculus quite well but don't know much about bundles and other modern stuff.

Comment: @Willie: thanks for the references, but at the first glance they appear to be a bit too technical.